# SwiftUI - TabView with NavigationView generates gray area

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, swiftui, ios13

I have some problems with my tabbed view when I set **isTranslucent** to **false** in combination with a **NavigationView**.

Does anyone know how to fix this? The problem is shown in the attached image.

I need translucent set to false otherwise I can't get the dark color.

[image]

Comment: Please post the code itself as plain text instead of (or in addition to) the screenshot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set backgroundColor. Don't set isTranslucent to false or it will create these artefacts you mentioned.

```swift
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .black
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .black
```

It becomes much darker. It isn't completely opaque though.

**Edit:** Just watched Modernizing Your UI for iOS 13 This is the way to do it :

The TabView and NavigationView are actually UIHostedController for the legacy UITabBarController and UINavigationController:

```
let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor  .white]
```

Then set the appearance on the various type of appearance.

```
tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
```

2nd Edit:

```swift
extension UINavigationController {
    override open func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
        navigationBar.compactAppearance = appearance
        navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }
}

extension UITabBarController {
    override open func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    }
}
```

There should be a cleaner way to get to both tabBar and navBar.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/224/

Answer (score 1):

I was using UIKit with SwiftUI. My Tab bar was creating in storyboard but the view for which I was getting extra bottom space was a swiftui view as you mentioned. I tried all above solution but Nothing worked for me.

I am using Xcode 12.4 for development. My solution is to mark Translucent to true in storyboard and Bottom extra gray bar was gone.

[image: See screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Just customize it in an extension like this:

```
extension UITabBarController {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
        appearance.backgroundColor = .black
        tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    }
}
```

Pay attention that the overridden function must be `viewDidLoad()`. At least it doesn't work for me when it is a `viewDidAppear(:)` function.

Answer (score -2):

It's easier than all that, just delete the next line:

```
UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```