# Navigation Link leading to gray screen in Swift UI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I am new to SwiftUI and am having a bug where my entire screen turns gray when I use too many Navigation Links.
I cannot find any solutions while researching the bug.
I am running the project on the newest version of Xcode 12.4.
My current setup is to have 2 different swiftUI Views, each containing a Navigation Link to the other.

[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChzsO.gif)

Code:

***PageOne.swift***

```
struct PageOne: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("This is page 1")
                    .font(.system(size: 36, weight: .bold))
                    .padding(.bottom)
                
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: PageTwo(),
                    label: {
                        VStack {
                            Text("Go to Page 2")
                                .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .medium))
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .frame(width: 200, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                                .background(Color.blue)
                                .cornerRadius(12)
                            
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

***PageTwo.swift***

```
struct PageTwo: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("This is page 2")
                    .font(.system(size: 36, weight: .bold))
                    .padding(.bottom)
                
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: PageOne(),
                    label: {
                        VStack {
                            Text("Go to Page 1")
                                .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .medium))
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .frame(width: 200, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                                .background(Color.blue)
                                .cornerRadius(12)
                            
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

[Project file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iTMUwm4yOCqFwnWdxREG1AgpYX0tBSPn/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: That's a lot of navigation views...

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61707588/12299030?

Comment: Same issue - doing this helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64868119/swiftui-navigation-view-opening-with-back-button-and-half-grey-screen-weird

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only have one `NavigationView` in the view hierarchy.

Try creating one `NavigationView` at the root level:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            PageOne()
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

and then remove `NavigationView` from subviews:

```
struct PageOne: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is page 1")
                .font(.system(size: 36, weight: .bold))
                .padding(.bottom)
            
            NavigationLink(
                destination: PageTwo(),
                label: {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Go to Page 2")
                            .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .medium))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .cornerRadius(12)
                        
                    }
                })
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

```
struct PageTwo: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is page 2")
                .font(.system(size: 36, weight: .bold))
                .padding(.bottom)
            
            NavigationLink(
                destination: PageOne(),
                label: {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Go to Page 1")
                            .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .medium))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .cornerRadius(12)
                        
                    }
                })
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```